# Socket.io across different Node.js routes

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I am building simple Node.js application that uses the Express Framework as well as Socket.io. I got stuck however trying to receive messages from the server across different express routes. Is there a way of receiving messages sent from one route to another route through the server? I've given a very simplified version of my code below:

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    http = require("http").createServer(app),
    fs = require("fs"),
    io = require("socket.io").listen(http);

//Create a server
var port = 9001;
http.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
});

//Set up routes
var anotherPage = express.Router();
anotherPage.route('/')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('/AnotherPage.html', {root: './public'});
});
var someOtherPage = express.Router();
someOtherPage.route('/')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('/SomeOtherPage.html', {root: './public'});
});

//Set up static directories
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))
    .use('/anotherpage', anotherPage)
    .use('/someotherpage', someOtherPage);

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.on("send message", function(data) {
    socket.emit('return message', data);
  });
});
```

#### Inside public folder

**AnotherPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sender</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/anotherPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button onclick="sendMessage()">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**anotherPage.js**

```
var socket = io.connect();

function sendMessage() {
  socket.emit("send message", document.getElementById('input').value );
}

socket.on('return message', function(data){
  //Working
  console.log(data);
});
```

**SomeOtherPage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Receiver</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script src="/someOtherPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  //TODO
</body>
</html>
```

**someOtherPage.js**

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('return message', function(data){
  //Not working
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the user has `anotherPage` loaded in the browser and clicks the button, the client sends `send message` to IO, IO sends `return message` back to the same client. `someOtherPage` is not even loaded at this moment, how would it receive `return message`?

Comment: Well assuming both are already loaded.

Comment: How would they both be loaded? Do you mean by different clients (or in different tabs, that are for all intents and purposes different clients)? Again, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes essentially different clients. To clarify again, basically have AnotherPage.js send a message using socket.io, then SomeOtherPage.js able to receive the message from a different route using socket.io.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, `socket.emit` on the server will send `return message` only to the one client, the same that it received `send message` from. If you want to send to anyone listening, use `io.sockets.emit` instead; or to all except `socket` with `socket.broadcast.emit`.

Basically, you are wondering why someone else can't eavesdrop on a private conversation. :) It has nothing to do with Express routing, and everything to do with `socket.io` API.

Comment: Yes thank you so simple `socket.broadcast.emit` was what I was looking for. How would you include the sender?

Comment: Sender's name, just include whatever string in the message. If you mean an ID to send a message, that's `socket.id`; you can send from server to a specific client using, IIRC, `io.clients[id].emit`.